# Waiting for props, but page wont render again

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to print a list of book titles from my fetched data, but its stuck on Loading... Is there a way to resolve my issue ? It might be because prop.id isn't ready when the page first renders ?

```
const Comp = (props) => {
    const [data,setData] = useState<any>([]);
    console.log(props.id);

      useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('url'+props.id,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
        }
        ).then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();
          }).then(function(myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
            setData(myJson)
          });
    },[])

    if (!data.book) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
        };
    
        return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.book.map(index => <li>{index.title}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
};

export default Comp;
```

The fetched data are of the form:

```
data = {
  "book": [
       {
         "id": "1",
         "title": "book1"
       }
       {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "book2"
       }
],
 "movie": [
       {
         "id": "1",
         "title": "movie1"
       }
       {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "movie2"
       }
]
}
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that `'url'+props.id` is a valid endpoint?

Comment: it is I just haven't written the actual endpoint url for safety reasons

Comment: You should include `props.id` in the dependency array of your useEffect if, as you suggest, it isn't available when the component mounts. Just check it is defined before making the fetch call.

Comment: @lawrence-witt tried that still doesn't work

Comment: What do all your console logs say?

Comment: Also react dev tools can show you what's in your component state... quite useful to help you see whether the problem is that your state isn't what you hoped it was or whether your logic for dealing with it is incorrect.

Comment: @lawrence-witt they are correct, It even looks like it doesnt have to wait for the props.id

Comment: Ok, well you think it looks correct but clearly something isn't. Please include it, especially `myJson`. We shouldn't have to ask you to post your debugging data.

Comment: The problem is that it goes to the if statement before the data have been set from fetch

Comment: But that `if` statement runs each time there's a re-render.  And calling `setData` will cause a re-render.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking for `data.question` but that doesn't exist in the data you posted. Only `data.book` and `data.movie` exist, so you're stuck in loading forever because you're looking for a property that doesn't exist even after the api call returns.

Comment: Yeah that's wrong from changing the code before I posted, I edited the question , that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a codesandbox that tries to mimic your code, substituting a `setTimeout` in place of your `fetch`.  Your books get rendered if there's a valid `data.book`, so I'm guessing that your fetch result isn't really getting into your state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-payne-j69yz

Also, your posted json isn't valid json, so maybe that's an issue?

One more fishy thing is that you're setting your initial state to an empty array `[]` but then when you call `setData` you're passing an object that is *not* an array. That makes me think your data you're receiving may not be the shape you expect it to be.  Hence my next comment...

Use the react dev tools to inspect the state for your `Comp` component, and see if the books are really there and with the correct shape:

[image]

```
const Comp = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(props.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Substitute for the fetch in the example code...
    setTimeout(() => {
      const myData = {
        book: [
          {
            id: "1",
            title: "book1"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            title: "book2"
          }
        ],
        movie: [
          {
            id: "1",
            title: "movie1"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            title: "movie2"
          }
        ]
      };
      setData(myData);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  if (!data.book) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.book.map((book, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{book.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useState` statement seems a bit odd. You are initializing the state as an empty array but you are expecting an object from the API.

```js
const [data,setData] = useState<any>([]);
```

You can ommit the empty array in this case and only write:

```js
const [data,setData] = useState<any>();
```

Then instead of relying on the data object you can include a loading state in order to display the `<span>Loading...</span>` markup instead.

```
const Comp = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const [data,setData] = useState<any>();
    console.log(props.id);

      useEffect(()=>{
        setIsLoading(true);

        fetch('url'+props.id,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
        }
        ).then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();
          }).then(function(myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
            setData(myJson)
          }).finally(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
          });
    },[props.id]) // Adding props.id to the dependecies will trigger an API call when that changes

    // By not initializing data on top we know that data is undefined until the API call is complete
    if (isLoading || !data) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
        };
    
        return(
        <div>
            // You can output the data directly on the DOM to check how your data look and if the `book` is actually `data.book` or on a different path
            <pre>
              {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
            </pre>
            <ul>
                {data.book.map(index => <li>{index.title}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
};

export default Comp;
```